# Finding intersected elements of lists in a dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary, interception

I'm working with Python 3 and I have a dictionary:

```
{'investment': [2,62,634,654], 
'companies': [2, 30, 62, 53, 66, 279, 281],
'products': [2, 30, 49,128,562,62]
 .
 .
 .
}
```

I don't know the size of dictionary. (It changes according to the input taken from the customer.)

The question is how can I fetch the interceptions of elements of the dictionary as an output? 
For the sample the final output should be `[2,62]`

Comment: `set.intersection(*map(set,d.values()))`

Comment: Hi,thanks for your answer. What about the nested list [[5,26],[6,121 ]] ? The set.intersection(*map(set,d.values())) get an error like TypeError: unhashable type: 'list' if the items which we want to compare also not an integer or string but a list.